# Is it always a requirement to declare a distribution model first before applying MCMC models/bayesian analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

I've read lot of articles that is using pymc python module to apply MCMC algorithms into solving real life problems. I found that all the examples are about to assume various kinds of distribution models first e.g. Poisson, Normal, Beta distributions, to the variables. This seems like a "must have" requirement to use Bayesian analysis. My question is, how do we know in advance that what distribution model we should use that best applies on the usecase? Is it going to change the results a lot if we used a "wrong" distribution model?

If this is a requirement, it seems it's a lot of more experience-related requirement. As a newbie, i really don't know too much more than very common distributions, how dare we could try some other distributions which require tons of more statistical knowledge before i use it?

Saying that, if i know not enough distribution models in advance, is that implying that i cannot build well a MCMC model to real life problems?

Comment: You are correct that a Bayesian inference begins with a prior distribution. That includes Bayesian inferences that use MCMC as a method for finding the posterior distribution. // Sometimes previous evidence or personal opinion indicates a prior distribution that is informative. Predicting election results in a setting where one party typically gets θ ≈ .5 of the vote, you might use BETA(50,50) as prior. If clueless about prior voting there you might use BETA(.5,.5) or BETA(1,1) = UNIF(0,1). // The posterior dist'n is a melding of prior dist'n and likelihood from data. ...

Comment: ... If you have lots of data, then the prior dist'n will have little effect on the posterior. // For example, if prior is BETA(1,1) and polling data show 2000 out of 3000 prefer the party in question, then posterior is easily seen to be BETA(2001, 1001) and 95% credible interval for θ would be (0.650, 0.683). // Then if 2nd poll comes along before there's much opportunity for opinion change, we might use highly informative BETA(2001,1001) as prior for analysis of 2nd poll. // An advantage of Bayesian methods is the _opportunity_ to include prior info in current analysis.

Comment: MCMC algorithms are tools for running Bayesian statistical models. They do not provide a statistical analysis on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to assume some priors, but you can build up [hierarchical models](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling) in pymc. Pairwise or more combinations of these very well known distributions might lead to highly sophisticated and strong models for explaining real world problems. Of course, some knowledge of these distributions will be quite useful in this process, e.g. Beta distribution for modelling probabilities (which is very useful due to its flexible shape by changing $\alpha, \beta$), Poisson for event occurrences, Exponential for inter-arrivals/lifetime, Geometric for lifetime/churn etc. Even a simple combination of Beta and Geometric distributions (which are also quite intuitive in this case) leads to successful retention analysis [in some works](http://www.brucehardie.com/talks/intro_tut_art_16_HO.pdf) by Hardie et al.